# How to match "abcabc" from "abcabced"?

Tags: lua

I could use `(abc)+` match `"abcabc"`
But how can I do in Lua ?
My way:

```
test = "abcabced"
get,getstr = "",""
while get ~= nil do
    get = string.match(test,"abc")
    getstr = getstr .. get
    test = string.gsub(test,get,"",1)
end
print(getstr)
```

Have better means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about the specific case of doing exactly what you asked for, the other two answers provide reasonable alternatives. If you're talking about the *general* case (searching for strings rather than characters)... you don't.

Lua's patterns are *not* regular expressions. They are just a pattern matching system. Their functionality is more limited than what you get with regexs, but the implementation is much smaller. If you need full regex support, you can find a [Lua library for that](http://rrthomas.github.com/lrexlib/).

Answer (score 1):

Try also this:

```
s="xabcabcabcyz"
p=""
t=nil
repeat
    m=t
    p=p.."abc"
    t=string.match(s,p)
until t==nil
print(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "abcabced"
results = {}
for match in string.gmatch(str, "abc") do
    table.insert(results, match)
end

print(table.concat(results))
```

Comment: This does not solve the same problem as posed by the OP. It find *all*  occurences of `"abc"`, not just the first contiguous repetition.